# Solving for elements of a conductance matrix, given the voltages at each node

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, current, analog, measurement

I'm trying to solve for the elements R12, R14, R23, R34 in the following circuit.
Resistances to ground R1, R2, R3, R4, voltages at nodes V1, V2, V3, V4, and input current I0 are all known.

[image]

The conductance matrix equation is shown below where Gij = 1/Rij.
This corresponds to a system of 4 linear equations with 4 unknown values (R12, R14, R23, R34).

[image]

If you sum these four equations, the result is independent of (R12,R14,R23,R34).
This is just proves that the net current flowing to ground is equal to the input current.

I am not sure how to solve this problem. Any ideas?

[image]

Edit:

If you try to combine the equations, you will find that the terms involving G12,G14,G23,G34 always cancel out, and you are left with only constants.

I think this means that the solution is degenerate (we cannot determine G12,G14,G23,G34 with only the given information).

Then, how would you measure this circuit to determine the values of these resistances?

Comment: Why dont you write for each node KCL instead?

Comment: Isn't this problem "trivial"?

Comment: @MissMulan The matrix equation is precisely the KCL, where each row corresponds to one of the four nodes (notice that G = 1/R)

Comment: @Antonio51 I dont think so... Do you have any ideas how to solve for (R12,R14,R23,R34)?

Answer (score 2):

With the available data, you can write a system of equations for currents at each of the 4 nodes:

$$
\begin{aligned}
I_{14} + I_{34} &= V_4/R_4\\
I_{23} - I_{34} &= V_3/R_3\\
I_{12} - I_{23} &= V_2/R_2\\
-I_{12} - I_{14} &= V_1/R_1-I_0\\
\end{aligned}
$$

where \$I_{12}\$ is the current going from node 1 to node 2; \$I_{23}\$ is going from node 2 to 3, etc.

This is a linear system with 4 unknowns and 4 equations.
Once this system is solved for \$I_{12},\ I_{23},\ I_{34}\$ and \$I_{14}\$, resistances \$R_{12}, R_{23}, R_{34}\$ and \$R_{14}\$ can be found using Ohms law.

Answer (score 0):

Write out your four equations.  Notice that all these symbols are known (they are all known numbers), except for g12, g14, g23, g24.  Move all of the known quantities to the right side of each your equations.

Now you have four linear equations in the four unknown conductances. Solve these simultaneously.

Comment: I did try that already, but I cannot find any linear combination that solves for g12, g14, g23, g24.

Comment: For example, if you combine (1 with 2) and (3 with 4), you get two expressions with only G12 and G23. If you combine those two, then the G12 and G23 terms cancel out. I cannot see another way to find a unique solution.
$$I_{0}-V_{12}G_{12}-V_{14}G_{14}-V_{1}G_{1}=0 \\ V_{12}G_{12}-V_{23}G_{23}-V_{2}G_{2} = 0 \\ V_{23}G_{23}-V_{34}G_{34}-V_{3}G_{3}=0\\ V_{14}G_{14}+V_{34}G_{34}-V_{4}G_{4}=0 $$

Here,
$$V_{ij}=V_i - V_j$$

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my other answer, **the "matrix" is not well "conditioned"**.

The reason is obvious.
**It can't be solved as a 4 equations system of 4 variables**.

De facto, it must be solved as **four independent systems** of **1 variable**.

Example of the **first circuit: R1, R12, R2** where voltages V1 and V2 are known.
**All other components do not matter.**

Then just apply the superposition theorem with currents.
Contribution of V1 :  \$ir1 = V1/R1\$ ; \$iR12V1 =  V1/R12 =  ir1 * R1 / R12\$
Contribution of V2 :  \$ir2 = V2/R2\$ ; \$iR12V2 = -V2/R12 = -ir2 * R2 / R12\$
So current through R12 => \$ir12 = iR12V1 + iR12V2 = ir1 * R1/R12 -ir2 * R2/R12\$

Does it deserve a bonus?   (EE&O).

Answer (score -1):

> how would you measure this circuit to determine the values of these resistances?

Try this (a simple case of 4 identical resistors.

[image]

And here is a more **general resolution, formulas (in RED) are algebraic**.

Made with [microcap v12](http://www.spectrum-soft.com/download/mc12cd.zip) which seems a **very good "solver" for checking**.

[image]

Comment: Sorry. Who downvoted has not tried resolving this set of equations!

Comment: The problem with this answer is that numerically solves the problem, while OP is asking for the algebraic solution. Of course this can be solved by identical resistors, or any resistor value, really - the question is about the relationship between node voltages and resistor values - you found two solutions, but there are several (infinite) more.

Comment: You don't read well my answer. **Sorry**. **The answers (in red) are "algebraically" described.** Example : **i(R14) = i(R1)/n14_1 - i(R4)/n14_4).** i(R1) = Vo1 / R1. i(R4)= Vo4/R4. All known. The definitions for n14_1 and n14_4 are given literally. The **DC analysis** gives simply a **"checking"** of the formulas ... It is not a numerical answer.

Comment: I stand corrected. I still do not think this answers OP question as it does not show the process of how to solve the equations "manually" and unfortunately I cannot remove my downvote... The site does not allow me.

Comment: @VladimirCravero No worries. Right about the process of solving. This "matrix" is not well "conditioned" ... and as it is, it can't be "resolved". My resolution was only **"intuitive"** ... See my new answer for "clarifying" the equations.